# A measure for level of experience

Tags: survey, ordinal-data

For a survey about mountain bike injuries I would like to obtain some information to allow me to quantify the level of experience of the rider. Ideally I would want to end up with some kind of ordinal variable in my analysis to indicate this.

However in the survey I was considering to ask something along the line of "How many years have you been riding MTB" and "During those years, how many hours a week (or month) have you been riding on average". So sort of a variation of the [package years measure for smoking exposure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack-year). Based on that I would then bin it somehow to get an ordinal variable.
Does any one know of any other, perhaps validated ways of quantifying experience?

Comment: This is an interesting question. A key term for you might be "[exposure](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK126191/)" in epidemiology.